# How to easily access the "high()" pseudo-function of an open array parameter in assembler?

Tags: delphi, assembly, parameter-passing

If it's the only parameter, its easy when using the register calling convention, but how about when using the Pascal calling convention? Let alone when I'm still shifting things around? Sure, I can look at the generated code, and copy that (every time...), but isn't there an easier way?

Comment: `High()` is a compiler intrinsic function.  There is no "function" being called at runtime, the compiler substitutes the call with the appropriate metadata.  For an **open array** parameter, which is really passed as two parameters - a pointer to the array elements, and the index of the last element of the array - just hidden behind code syntax, eg `procedure proc(Arr: array of T)` is really `procedure proc(Arr: T^; High_Arr: Integer)`, then calling `High()` on an open array parameter simply replaces the call with the index parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The [official Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control_(Delphi)#Passing_Parameters) states the following:

> An open-array parameter is passed as two 32-bit values. The first value is a pointer to the array data, and the second value is one less than the number of elements in the array.

(just to be clear, the 32-bit is to be changed into 64-bit on Win64)

But the main point is that an open array is passed as two parameters:

- one pointer to the first value of the `array of const`
- one NativeInt containing `high()`, i.e. `length()-1` of this `array of const`

So in assembly, you just code for instance:

```
procedure MyAsmProc(const args: array of const);
asm
  // here eax = @args[0] as PVarRec
  // and  edx = high(args);
end;
```

On the `pascal` calling convention, just use the proper stack position instead of the register, as detailed in the doc (but who uses the `pascal` calling convention????).

Internally the `array of const` is in fact an `array of TVarRec` as defined in system.pas:

```
PVarRec = ^TVarRec;
TVarRec = record { do not pack this record; it is compiler-generated }
  case Byte of
    vtInteger:    (VInteger: Integer; VType: Byte);
    vtBoolean:    (VBoolean: Boolean);
 ...
```

So you can access to the stored value type by checking its `VType` member (vtInteger, vtBoolean...).

Comment: It's not necessarily array of const

Comment: I have my reasons to use the Pascal calling convention. And for what it's worth, if I were to add a second open array parameter, which is not unlikely, I'd be forced to use stack positions anyway. And Thank you for reminding me, but I do know how open array parameters are passed, since about the days of Borland (or was it even Turbo) Pascal.

Comment: Page 235 (246 in the PDF) of the Turbo Pascal 7.0 manual @ http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/borland/turbo_pascal/Turbo_Pascal_Version_7.0_Language_Guide_1992.pdf gives the solution.

Comment: So if you know this information, I don't understand the relevance of your question.  There is no difference if you pass two open arrays: you just have to handle 4 parameters on the stack, and the 2nd and the 4th being the high() of each open array. What did you try as asm? Do you need help about the pascal calling convention?

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: I knew about open array parameters since about forever, having used Pascal since TP version 2, but I had never used them in assembler, only in "pure" pascal, where the intrinsics take care of the nitty-gritty. What I needed was an easy way of accessing the data that's normally returned by the "high()" intrinsic, and after posting my question, I continued searching and that's when I stumbled on the searchable(!) PDF of the TP7 manuals.